# Keep cab external to msi

Tags: c#, setup-deployment

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to create an MSI package. I want to create a package that contains NO files internally but only an external cab file with all the files into it, to enable modification at the client side. Can anyone tell me how this is possible?
Also, how can I modify the external cab file using C#.

Comment: Can you please explain your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Windows Installer. The CAB is only a container for the files. The actual file information is stored in the MSI database.